# Prove or disprove every base of $\mathbb{R} $ as vector space over rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ , contain $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, real-numbers

Prove or disprove every base of $\mathbb{R} $ as vector space over rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$  , contain $\mathbb{Q}$ . I think that this is true because every base of $\mathbb{R} $ as vector space over rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$  must be infinite and countable .

Comment: Are $1$ and $2$ $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent?

Comment: Your last sentence is false. A basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ must be *un*countable.

Comment: Any basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$ can contain at most one element of $\Bbb Q$. Thus your claim is false as stated. I suppose you meant to claim that every basis must contain one element of $\Bbb Q$, but even this is not correct, as @HelloDarkness points out.

Comment: Please do not add inappropriate tags at random.

Answer (score 2):

$\{1\} \cup \{ \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}\}$ generates $ \mathbb{R}$, so there is a base contained in it, but not every rational number is in there.

Comment: Just $\{1\}\cup(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)$ works.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

(1)... A basis cannot contain $0.$ Any two non-$0$ rationals are linearly dependent over $\Bbb Q$ so a basis can have at most one rational member.

(2)...$\sqrt 2$ and $1+\sqrt 2$ are linearly dependent over $\Bbb Q$ so there exists a basis $B$ with $B\supset \{\sqrt 2, 1+\sqrt 2\}.$ And no member of $\Bbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ is linearly independent of $\{\sqrt 2, 1+\sqrt 2\}$ so $B\cap \Bbb Q$ is empty.

(3)... If $v$ is a non-$0$ vector then $\{v\}$ is a linearly independent set so there exists a basis $C$ with $C\supset \{v\}.$ In particular when $v=1.$

(4)... If $D$ is a countable subset of $\Bbb R$ then the set of finite linear combinations of members of $D,$ with rational co-efficients, is only a countable set, so $D$ cannot be a basis for $\Bbb R.$